# Azure failed request error details

Tags: azure

I've got an Azure app up and running, but various requests generate a 500 error. There are no other details that come back from the server to let me know exactly what the problem is. No stack trace, no error message. The only thing I get back from the server are the http headers indicating I've got an error.

I've done a little looking around but can't seem to find a way to retrieve the error details that I'm looking for. I've seen some articles that suggest that I enable logging, but I'm not sure 1) how to do that, 2) where those log files would go and 3) how to access said log files. I've seen posts that say to add a whole bunch of code to my application to enable logging, but all I'm looking for is an error message and a stack trace from a 500 error. Do I really have to add a bunch of code to my app to see that information? If not, how can I get at it?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

The best long-term solution is to enable Azure Diagnostics, which I think is what you're referring to. If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you can log errors out to a file and then RDP into the role instances to view them. This is very similar to what you would do on a server in your own datacenter.

You can create the logs however you like. I've used log4net and RollingFileAppenders with some success. Setting the logfile path to something like "\logs\mylog.txt" will place the logs in the E: drive of the VM. Note you'll still need code somewhere in your app to capture the error and write it to the log - typically the global error handler in Global.asax is a good place for that.

You'll also have to enable RDP access to your role instances. There are many articles detailing how to do that. [Here's one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx).

This is not a generally recommended approach because the logs may disappears when the role recycles or is recreated. It's also a pain in the butt to log to keep an eye on all those different servers.

One other warning - it's possible that the 500 error is due to some failure in your web.config. If that is the case, all the the application-level error logging in the world isn't going to help you. So be sure that your web.config is valid, and also check the Windows Event Logs while you're RDP'd into the server.

Answer (score 0):

500 internal server error is most generally caused by some problem on the server when it was not able to understand incoming requests or there was some problem in configuration. So, try to run the app locally and see if there is some problem. You can record errors in a database in catches/application_error and also can use tracing. Believe me they are very helpful and worth a few extra lines of code.

For tracing have a look here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx